# Predicting a timeframe for a percentage of occurrence based off initial results

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

If I have a group of individuals and within an initial timeframe of six months I observe that 25% of this group are impacted by an event I am measuring (let's say they were robocalled), how long until 90% are robocalled?

I initially assumed something linear but was looking for general guidance. Thanks.

Edit: At the request of the below: if 25% of 1000 subjects are robocalled within six months of measuring that occurrence.  How long until 90% are robocalled?

Edit 2: Adjusted the first paragraph as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added to the main question: If 25% of 1000 subjects are robocalled within six months of measuring that occurrence. How long until 90% are robocalled?

Comment: This is still not a good question. Are you *telling* us that a linear extrapolation approach is the relevant model and need help using it, or *asking* whether a linear extrapolation is adequate? (It isn't -- I think -- but there's not much in the question to say so.

Comment: The latter, asking whether a linear extrapolation is adequate for this purpose.  If not, then what... Assume this is all the information on hand so what's the best approximation to answer the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The only information you provide is that within 6 months, 25% have been affected. Note that this is actually a single data point, and therefore it is impossible to extrapolate. But assuming that at time 0, 0% have been affected, we now have two data points and can extrapolate.

It is reasonable to extrapolate linearly if the observed rate of 250 persons affected (out of 1000) every 6 months is constant at the 6 month time scale. However, keep in mind that it is imprecise to make a statement at a finer time scale, so the most precise answer would be that at some point between 18 months and 24 months, 90% will have been affected.

(Again, this is if you assume a constant rate, which may not be the case if this is a real example. If this is real, the best answer is to try to get more information.)

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. I really appreciate the thoughtful and thorough answer.  Thanks again!